# Owl Carousel Volusion Installation

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel, volusion

I am trying to install a full page width version of Owl Carousel on my Volusion site. I would like for the slider to display directly below the navigation.

Their documentation seems simple enough but I guess I am somehow placing the css/js/html in the wrong place because it's not working.

In the head I am linking to the css, at the bottom of the body I am linking to the js. The file I downloaded and am trying to use is here: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/download/owl.carousel.zip

It only includes 1 css file and 2 js files and their documentation references other files I don't see in the zip. This is probably quite simple, I am just lost.

Comment: try this link the download here contain the demos and other files http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Comment: if it did not work then add your code here so we can help you

Comment: I was able to download what I believe to be the 'correct version' thanks to your link. I believe the issue is now that different versions of jquery may be conflicting? I believe there is too much code to copy/paste. Any suggestions?

Comment: well i can't suggest any thing unless i see your code to know what's going wrong , if your using more than one version of jquery it may cause conflict why don't you stick to jquery-1.9.1.min.js which come with the demo of the owl carousel

Comment: I tried to take out all the irrelevant content and hopefully left anything you would need to see... It was still too many characters so I pasted it here: http://jsfiddle.net/xjvtx63e/

Comment: my friend i can't understand anything from the code you pasted there is no css style and even the html is not obvious where is the carousel wrapper and the java script is to messy and i believe there are mistakes in it please clear the fiddle so it could be understood or if you want a help with example just add a pic or a link to something similar to your need

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. This is the template I am using where you can see that jquery is already present. http://hipster-demo.volusion.com/

Comment: I discovered that volusion uses an older version of jquery that can't be changed. So I need the ability to use a different version just for the owl slider. This is where I am stuck currently.

Comment: if you want to use more than one jquery try looking for jQuery.noConflict() i hope it works for you . this is a link contain some useful information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page